# Entity Framework 3.5: Saving objects in stages with separate contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In C# and Entity Framework 3.5, I have a context with several million records. This takes about 2 GB of RAM. As soon as I call `SaveChanges()`, it starts filling up my 8 GM RAM and starts swapping.

I used a profiler and it turned out that it was the SQL querie(s) that hogged the memory.

Now I want to save in batches, but I'm running into problems.

I have a collection of `Locations` (which in turn have collections and subcollections of stuff). When I split that in batches and assign a new context to each, as soon as I do `context.AddToOrder(firstBatch)`, *ALL* locations in *all* batches suddenly have entity state `Added`, even though they don't have an `Order`. This makes the save fail because the `Order -> Location` relation doesn't exist.

Why do all the objects in the original collection get state `Added` when I only add a subset of those to the context?

Comment: Are you sure that all that memory have been used by application? or maybe it was used by Sql Server.

Comment: All that sql query string has to be generated somewhere and I'm guessing that would be the ram. How about saving only chunks of it, maybe using a transaction scope.

Comment: It's not the SQL server, that's another machine. And about transaction scope; that's maybe a possibility, but the last time I tried that (a few weeks ago), it required so many weird settings on the server, I stopped it. And it required a reboot, and I can't reboot the server right now. Anyway, after looking at the activity monitor, the SQL is indeed not being executed yet while it's consuming RAM.

Comment: You definitely should save your data by chunks. And it's not safe to hold a large amount of data only in RAM because if your system crashes anything will be lost.
Transactions should work fine.

Comment: The safety is not an issue; I generate these records from scratch and then save them.

Comment: So all of the objects are new ? Is it a single object type instance, or are there mutliple related object type instances in the context ?

Comment: If you're doing a lot of processing on large data sets consider using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). This allows you to define a data flow from a source to a target with the possibility of introducing data transformations. It will stream the rows from the source to the target so you'll have less problems with memory (though beware not to do any sorting in the data flow, as this batches the stream).

Answer (score 2):

> I have a context with several million records. This takes about 2 GB of RAM.

I know you will not like this answer but it simple. **Don't do that.** EF and especially EFv1 is not ready for this. EF is not tool for even handling tens of MBs. You must use some other tool for such big data sets or divide your update into multiple (in your case thousands or even millions) small change sets each using its own context.

I guess when you call `SaveChanges` EF will try to do its magic including detecting changes in your entities and preparing statements to execute. There can be memory leaks but there can be also a lot of unreleased memory due to GC. In such case there is nothing to do with your current problem.

Btw. EF will try to store your modifications in single transaction. So if you are trying to save 2GB in single transaction you can expect problems on many more levels.

Comment: That is because calling Add will add everything in object graph, not only single location. So if your location has navigation property of stuff, stuff is added as well and if stuff has navigation collection of locations, all that locations will be added as well. It is not so easy to divide it. It will not work when you already have 2GB of interconnected objects. You must process objects in batches and build only relations which exists in that batch.

Comment: As far as I can tell, one location should be linked to another through 'stuff'; one location and it's 'stuff' should be completely self-contained. But I'll check again to make sure.